# Calling an .exe without the extension, but with -i

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working on integrating the functions of a batch file into a larger PowerShell file (that does other things too) so I can eventually get rid of some smaller batch files.

I came across a line that looks like this:

```
if exist "C:\path\thing.exe" 
("C:\path\thing" -i "C:\otherpath\something.dll")
```

What is it referencing in the second line when it says the .exe name but with no file extension?

**EDIT**: I ran a `/?` on the .exe, I think this might be relevant:

```
/i <assembly_path> [ /r <...> ] [ /f ]
    Installs an assembly to the global assembly cache. <assembly_path> is the
    name of the file that contains the assembly manifest.
    Example: /i myDll.dll /r FILEPATH c:\projects\myapp.exe "My App"
```

So I guess the `-i` is running the .exe using the .dll file as some kind of config file?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The only other thing with that name in the folder is `thing.exe.config`. How does it know which to reference?

Comment: it'll find extensions in `%PATHEXT%`. But why do you care what's it's doing? Just check for the existence of the binary and then run `"C:\path\thing" -i "C:\otherpath\something.dll"` as in the batch file. All the things after the first are parameters are are not related to calling the file with exe or not

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You're right. I just wanted to be sure it wasn't doing something fancy that I might miss when converting it to PowerShell. Also I didn't know if running `thing` without an extension was even possible in PowerShell.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Why would that be the case? I could just say `if exist "thing1.exe" (somethingelse.exe)`. I meant why, when given no extension, does it automatically go to `thing.exe` instead of `thing.exe.config`, or if there was other stuff like `thing.bat` or `thing.whatever`?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120 and scroll down to 'command search sequence' heading. PowerShell command resolution is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Command_Precedence

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Oh cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you can run executable files (with .exe suffix) without the extension from the command line.

So this is perfectly valid:

```
"C:\path\thing" -i "C:\otherpath\something.dll"
```

In this command, `-i` is an argument to the executable. It is probable that the correct syntax is `-i path\to\a\file.dll` so the dll is used by the executable. It's difficult to say more since your question is very generic

To understand, try to run xcopy in CMD or PowerShell:

```
xcopy /?
```

In this example, xcopy is the executable, corresponding to C:\System32\xcopy.exe and `/?` is an argument to the command, explaining all possible arguments supported by xcopy.

Actually, this works too:

```
C:\Windows\System32\xcopy.exe /?
```

but since C:\Windows\System32 is listed in the %Path% environment variable, you can call xcopy directly without specifying its folder.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

When executing a command that does not contain an extension, `cmd.exe` uses the value(s) of the `%PATHEXT%` variable:

```
SET PATHEXT
```

It will supplement each entry in the order listed as a replacement extension until successful or all have been tried.

As you will note it is unlikely that the first entry will show as `.EXE` and I would suggest therefore that your new method reverts to the full name with extension `thing.exe`.